# VUEJS How to post to other website api?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I want to post to my api website

> The index.js

`proxyTable: {
      '/api': {
            target: 'http://example.com',
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }
        }
    },`

> Login.vue script

```
  submit() {
  this.$http.post('/api/user/login/',{
    'username':this.username,
    'password':this.password
    }).then(function(data){}
}
```

But check the Developer Tools, the error is

GET http://localhost:8080/api/user/login 500 (Internal Server Error)

So why the action is not POST http://example.com/api/user/login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs. The HTTP method is not defined in the options:

```
this.$http.post('/someUrl').then(response => {

    // get body data
    this.someData = response.body;

  }, response => {
    // error callback
  });
```

To se a base URL for all your request you have to go this way:

```
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://example.com';
```

I suggest you to use axios instead thought

Comment: Thank  you, I changed my code, but still POST http://localhost:8080/api/user/login 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I don't believe you :)

This works and it's taken from the docs:

this.$http.post('/someUrl', [body], [config]).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

Comment: I mean it should POST http://example.com/api/user/login ? But why localhost

Comment: I'm not sure what you did in index.js with the proxyTable object...

But I updated my answer with how to configure the base URL for all requests.

Comment: if I do this
{this.$http.post('http://example.com')}
 the error is (Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.)

Comment: That's because example.com doesn't allow POST requests from any domain. Use your now, and if it's your API take a look into CORS and the famous OPTIONS request verb

Comment: yeah, that what I do in the index.js... Try to fix the CORS problem... But Unfortunately...

Comment: There to better way to say thanks than accepting the answer here at Stackoverflow. Welcome to the community